# How to move TortoiseSVN repository and working copy both from one PC to another

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm moving from PC1 to PC2 - both are `windows 10`. PC1 has only one repository and only one working folder of a project. PC1 has `TortoiseSVN` installed. All the checkouts/checkin/commits etc are done via `TortoiseSVN`. I've installed `TortoiseSVN` on PC2 as well. **Question**: What would be a simplest way to move repository and working folder to PC2 while still keeping the change history etc. on PC2. **Note**: Everything is done via `TortoiseSVN` only.

Comment: Make sure that everything is committed and there are no pending changes in your working copy. Then just delete working copy. Make a dump of the repository on the first PC and then create a new repository on the second PC and import the dump. Last, create a new working copy. Maybe you can copy the repository directly to the new PC. For creating the dump you should have the `svnadmin` command line tools installed (it's an option during the TortoiseSVN installation).

Comment: @royalTS When installing `TortoiseSVN` on second PC, I did not choose the option for command line utilities. Is there something I can still install; otherwise, what are the other ways to install command line utility for `TortoiseSVN `?

Comment: Just run the installation a second time and select the option.

Comment: @royalTS You mentioned I may just copy the repository directly to the new PC. I've done that. Now would you know how do I copy connect my new working copy to the newly copied repository?

Comment: Just create a new working copy with the link from the new repository

Comment: @royalTS Your last comment with a combination of your first comment resolved my issue (thank you). For the benefit of other readers of this post, you may want to convert your comments into a `Response` and I'll mark it as an answer so the other users can benefit from that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that everything is committed and there are no pending changes in your working copy. Then just delete the working copy.

Depending on your configuration you might be able to simply copy the complete repository to the new PC or you need to make a dump of the repository, create a new repository and import the dump. For creating a dump you should have installed the `svnadmin` command line tools (it´s an option during the TortoiseSVN installation).

Then simply create a new working copy from the new repository, to start working again.